# CSS Multiple Animations

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit

I have a `div` with an intro `animation` and on click I add a new class called 'exit' with a new animation, but the animation dont work.

```
div { animation: intro steps(14) 1s 1;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    }

div.exit { animation: exit steps(18) 1s 1;
           animation-fill-mode: forwards;
         }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please show some fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fsqp7vgk/

Answer (score 0):

The animation is working, but you tell it to go to 0px.

If you say:

```
@keyframes exit {
    0% { background:yellow; }
    100% { background:black; }
}
```

It is working: http://jsfiddle.net/fsqp7vgk/1/

So, the animation is working, but you tell it again to go to position 0px. The solution is to specify in `.exit {left:500px;}` //your previous position.

Here it is with move animation: http://jsfiddle.net/fsqp7vgk/2/

```
.exit {animation:exit 5s 1; left:500px; }

@keyframes intro {
    0% { left:100px; }
    100% { left:500px; }
}
@keyframes exit {
    0% { left:500px; }
    100% { left:0px; }
}
```

Of course, keep `-webkit- prefix` if you use chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine, you got it wrong  in following code.

You forgot to add **px** `after 500.`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fsqp7vgk/3/)**

```
@-webkit-keyframes exit {
    0% {
        left:500px;
    }
    100% {
        left:0;
    }
}
```